# Aid NumPy to create array from object

Tags: python, numpy

Given an object that is both iterable but also can efficiently convert itself to a NumPy array, what can I use to help NumPy create an array from it? `__array_interface__`?

```
# Naive class that need to be iterated over
class myclass1():
    def to_array(self):
        return np.arange(4)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i > 3:
            raise IndexError
        return i

    def __len__(self):
        return 4

# "Smart" class that knows how to construct NumPy buffer
class myclass2():
    # The result is always the same, but there is no buffer that is
    # part of the instance. Instead the buffer is generated when
    # calling to_array()
    def to_array(self):
        return np.arange(4)

    @property
    def __array_interface__(self):
        data = self.to_array()
        return {
            'shape': (4,),
            'data': data,
            'typestr': data.dtype.str,
        }


a = myclass1()
np.array(a)

b = myclass2()
np.array(b)
```

Or does this produce memory leaks, double frees or other memory ownership issues?

Comment: You might want to modify your question to add that the original object is immutable.

Comment: While I use `__array_interface__` to check if an array is a copy, I only know of one case where the values are set or modified, and that is `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`.  If you don't do it right you can address memory outside of the buffer.

Comment: Yes, but if you make a *copy* in the `__array_interface__`, what's the point?!  The whole idea is to provide an array-like *view* into the data.

Comment: I've changed the code a bit to highlight that the result of `to_array()` doesn't randomly change, but also that there is no buffer that is part of the instance.

Comment: @wim Ah, I didn't know that. The point is: I want to speed up conversion. Converting an iterable class one element after another may be very slow, and the class has logic that is more efficient.

Comment: I have changed the code again to highlight the difference between the two types of classes.

Comment: @user2357112 why did you delete your `__array__` answer?